# MongoDB returns all records even after specifying fields

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

```
> db.checklistDB.find({},{title:1, _id:0})
{ "title" : "Untitled Checklist" }
{  }
{  }
{  }
{  }
{  }
> db.checklistDB.find({},{title:1})
{ "title" : "Untitled Checklist", "_id" : "4FaJcAkzAY3Geyggm" }
{ "_id" : "3imNYy8SPcRDjLcqz" }
{ "_id" : "977fPtvEn7hiStqzp" }
{ "_id" : "QcAEMnr6R7qfaWFR8" }
{ "_id" : "eEsmKMdQGYKqnhTNB" }
{ "_id" : "cL6R8qxwWhvTr2kmy" }
```

Hi Guys,

As you can see from the above, I rand 2 commands:

*db.checklistDB.find( {} , { title : 1 } )*  and
*db.checklistDB.find( {} , { title : 1 , _id : 0} )

Both queries returns 6 records which is all the records that exists in the database. I would imagine that it will only return records that have "title" as a field. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second argument for find is projection. In your case it looks for `title` field inside document, and if it doesn’t exist returns `none`. If you want to filter documents you should use query like this:

```
 db.checklistDB.find({title: {$exists: true}}, {title:1, _id:0})
```

**EDIT**
If you take your query:

```
db.checklistDB.find({}, {title:1, _id:0})
```

It translates to: retrieve all documents (`{}` as query argument) and for every document give me `title` if  exist or default value (`none`) if it doesn’t (`{title:1, _id:0}` as projection argument). Projection argument is used only to transform not to filter documents.

Comment: I would've thought that my query would translate to: 

Select title from checklistDB; 

which returns all titles which is correct, but it somehow also includes all the _ids of every other records. 

Where as your query goes something like 

select title from checklistdb where exists title;

But it works :) Thanks!

Comment: I've posted short update with a little bit better explanation.